# Unsecure windows domain join using NetJoinDomain API

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, dns

We are using a cloning technology inside our company, and we join newly cloned VMs to the domain using windows NetJoinDomain API--

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmjoin/nf-lmjoin-netjoindomain

Also, we are using unsecured domain join, as specified in the above link. This is the exact way we are calling this API --:

```
NetJoinDomain(NULL,
                        (LPCWSTR) _policy->GetDomainFqdn().c_str(),
                        NULL, NULL,
                        (LPCWSTR) passwdPtr->c_str(),
                        NETSETUP_JOIN_DOMAIN |
                        NETSETUP_DOMAIN_JOIN_IF_JOINED |
                        NETSETUP_JOIN_UNSECURE |
                        NETSETUP_MACHINE_PWD_PASSED);
```

For all the cloned VMs, the passwdPtr is the string "password". This is working for all customers, except for one, where NetJoinDomain is returning incorrect password. Any idea what could be the reason. Since we are doing unsecure join, any password should work here, right? Or am i missing anything here. Any pointers would be helpful here.

Comment: *"Any idea what could be the reason."* - You are silencing the compiler that's trying to help you spot bugs. Remove your `(LPCWSTR)` casts and let the compiler do its thing. If it causes an error, fix the bug.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but why do you think the cast might be causing the problem? Basically it should accept any password right? I am just trying to understand the rootcause

Comment: Do you understand what your code does?

Comment: `This is working for all customers, except for one.` So could you compare this VM with other different details to help us find the problem? And if you set the `NETSETUP_JOIN_UNSECURE` and `NETSETUP_MACHINE_PWD_PASSED` flags, you can indeed set any password.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So it should work with ANY password. That was my doubt. Looks like some restrictive GPO setting is causing the issue.

Comment: The point is that even if any password is accepted, the password still has to be a valid string. Apparently you are calling the variant that expects a UTF-16 encoded string. Not every sequence of bytes forms a valid sequence of UTF-16 code units.

Comment: It is not possible to determine whether the error is caused by your password string. Perhaps you can refer to: [NetJoinDomain error 1326 when using UnsecureJoin](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/55549965-8015-4e87-adad-badfd04579ba/netjoindomain-error-1326-when-using-unsecurejoin?forum=w7itproinstall), [Domain join account still fails with error 1326](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/49b4e082-c189-4b82-9c0d-e3f0b925d562/domain-join-account-still-fails-with-error-1326?forum=configmgrgeneral)